# How can more than 2 complex numbers satisfy a quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ is satisfied by more than 2 complex numbers, then the given equation 
>     becomes an identity, that is a = b = c = 0.

But how can more than 2 complex numbers satisfy a quadratic equation. It has 2 roots atmost.

Comment: Only non-constant quadratics are guaranteed to have at most two roots.

Comment: Yes, quadratics over *any* field only have at most two different roots, so if a quadratic (complex, rational, real...) has more than two different roots, then... Note that here the use of the noun "quadratic" is being made in the weak sense: it is allowed to have $\;a=0\;$ , say.

Comment: The answer is already at the end of the sentence: it's possible for more than two complex numbers to satisfy $ax^2+bx+c=0$ precisely if $a=b=c=0$. Did you read that?

Comment: If $\;a\neq 0\;$ then there can't be more than two different roots of the quadratic. Period.

Comment: The question has now been edited into nonsense.

Comment: I agree with Peter...the first edition was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how can more than 2 complex numbers satisfy a quadratic equation. It has 2 roots atmost.

The usual convention is to take a quadratic equation to be of the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ where $a \neq 0$. And then indeed a quadratic will only have at most two roots (whether  we are playing with the rationals, reals, complex numbers ...).

But what if we don't require $a$ to be non-zero? Then we can consider the special case where $a = b = c = 0$, and then -- in this special case -- the trivial equation is satisfied by any value of $x$ in the relevant field, and the equation has more than two roots.

[What we can't have, to address one version of the question (now re-edited), is *both* $a \neq 0$ and no more than two roots *and* $a = b = c = 0$ and more than two roots.]

Comment: then it can be satisfied by more than 2 real numbers also???

Comment: The equation $0x^2+0x+0=0$ is satisfied by every number.

Comment: Ah the question has been edited again ...